# Installing Erlang without GTK

Tags: erlang, fedora, system-administration

I'm trying to get Erlang working on my Fedora server, specifically to run rabbitmq, but when I `yum install erlang` yum complains that wxGTK requires a bunch of packages.

Wtf? Why is erlang trying to install a GUI? I intend to deploy this on a headless server.

Do I need to compile erlang from source? Is there no GUI-less version of erlang I can use?

Answer (score 6):

I like to use [the kurl script](http://wiki.basho.com/Installing-Erlang.html) created by the folk at Basho to install Erlang. It works very well on ubuntu. I hope this will be ok on Fedora too.

This will actually automatically download the source code, and compile it. If you dont have Wx installed, it will not compile this library and will work perfectly without (as long as you dont use tools which need it, of course)

Answer (score 2):

I guess by default your erlang installation has wxErlang enabled and so those packages are required for installation.

On https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Installation you can find instructions on how to manually install Erlang/OTP.

In the configure part you can disable the wxErlang part. Usually no extra config is required since the wxErlang-support will be disabled by default when the required packages are not installed.

Answer (score 0):

With Fedora 38 at least, `dnf install erlang-tools` appears to be the answer.